# Spring Security Custom Login Processing URL always redirecting to failurehandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am developing a code with spring security with annotation based configuration.

But after hitting the login processing url defined in **configure** method of **WebSecurityConfig** Class (which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** ) from login page its always redirecting to **.failureHandler()** method of **httpSecurity** rather than **.successHandler()** even if correct **username** and **password** is provided.

Following is the **configure** method and **configureGlobal** method of **WebSecurityConfig** class.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login.success").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.home")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
            .successHandler(applicationLoginSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(applicationLoginFailureHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");

}
```

here is the snippet of **login.jsp**

```
<c:url value="login.do" var="loginUrl"/>
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="POST">         
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">          
        <p>  
            Invalid username and password.  
        </p>  
    </c:if>  
    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">         
        <p>  
            You have been logged out.  
        </p>  
    </c:if>  
    <p>  
        <label for="username">Username</label>  
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>      
    </p>  
    <p>  
        <label for="password">Password</label>  
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>      
    </p>  
    <input type="hidden"                          
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  
        value="${_csrf.token}"/>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>  
</form>
```

What i am missing ?

i am using spring security 5.1.2.release

Answer (score 0):

Login page and logout page must be accessable for everyone. You  have missed  **.pemitAll() method**  after  login config and after logout config.

Comment: i tried with .loginPage("/login.home").permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password") , but no luck .

Comment: I think it happens  because of user credentials. Check this, change **.password(...)** method in **configureGlobal(...)** method with **.password("{noop}pass")**.

Comment: `@Override`
 `public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)`
   `throws IOException, ServletException {`
  `httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);`
  `httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("./login.success");`
  `HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();`
  
 `}` This is the successHandler's **onAuthenticationSuccess** method. is there anything to do with Send Redirect method ???

Answer (score 0):

Its been working. Actually i missed a password encoder for this. While i gave one its redirecting to success page.